# Cascading routers - secondary router as VPN?

Tags: router, vpn

I have two routers: Router A and Router B. Router A is my "primary" router (it serves my internet connection directly). I want to cascade or daisy-chain Router B as a secondary router of A, but the catch is, I want it to be dedicated to a VPN connection; I want everything connected to Router B to flow through a VPN.

Is this possible to do?

Thanks for reading

Comment: As a theory, sure it is possible.  However without knowing details that you left out, there is no way we could provide a real practical answer.  To start with, you would need to provide the make/model and possibly software version running on the routers.

Comment: I disagree with your down vote. I was not looking for a step by step answer that was specific to any hardware. I thought it was assumed that the equipment was technically capable of the required operations, which is why I asked in the first place.

Comment: You are certainly entitled to your opinion, as am I.  Currently the question is too vague to be of any use or to have any answer of use to others.  If you knew the equipment was capable of the required operations, then you wouldn't have needed to ask the question in the first place.  Sure, you can set up a router to do VPN behind another router; pretty much every VPN service works that way since the internet is built on thousands of routers.  Whether your equipment is capable of doing so in the fashion you want really depends on what it is.

Comment: I think the question is valid as presented @YLearn.

Comment: @DavidSemeria, the problem with the question is that the correct answer *is "Maybe, it depends on if your hardware has the required features/capabilities." This is a terrible answer, but forced by the manner in which the question is asked. The OP's response was that the hardware is capable of doing it. If the OP knew the hardware could do this, why are they asking? This likely means that the question as stated isn't quite what the OP wanted to ask and the question should be improved. While you may not agree with me, clearly others have (btw, I didn't down vote until after my second comment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this will work. These types of setups are common for when you have a group of computers that need to be connected through a VPN, and another group of computers to be connected directly to the Internet. In your question you didn't specify if you needed split VPN. (the computers on router B needing to access the Internet) However in this situation I would probably use 1 router with 2 VLAN's for the 2 groups.

Comment: Thanks! That's all the info I really needed. I appreciate your help.